# Filter and return all rows of a group where specific row fulfills one condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to filter and retrieve all rows from all groups where a specific row meets a condition, in my example when the value is more than 3 at the highest day per group. This is obviously simplified but breaks it down to the essential.

```
# Dummy data
id = rep(letters[1:3], each =  3)
day = rep(1:3, 3)
value = c(2,3,4,2,3,3,1,2,4)
my_data = data.frame(id, day, value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My approach works, but it seems somewhat unsmart:

```
require(dplyr)
foo <- my_data %>%
         group_by(id) %>% 
         slice(which.max(day)) %>% # gets the highest day
         filter(value>3)           # filters the rows with value >3

## semi_join with the original data frame gives the required result: 

semi_join(my_data, foo, by = 'id')
  id day value
1  a   1     2
2  a   2     3
3  a   3     4
4  c   1     1
5  c   2     2
6  c   3     4
```

Is there a more succint way to do this?

Comment: `my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(max(value) > 3)` ?

Comment: This doesnt work, because the highest value is not necessarily on the highest day. That's only the case in my example

Comment: `my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(max(value[which.max(day)]) > 3)`?

Comment: @Relasta was faster ;) Thanks many times. I wasn't thinking enough. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(value[which.max(day)] > 3)
```